# Codeigniter: Include actual input value from validation error message

Tags: php, codeigniter

Good day!

Fast newbie question.

I have this validation from controller:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules("item_name", "Item Name", "trim|xss_clean|max_length[100]|required|is_unique[tbl_item.item_name]");
// UPDATE: as suggested by Asad Khan and NARGIS PARWEEN, 
// I changed this:
// $this->form_validation->set_message("is_unique", "This %s already exists.");
// into this:
$this->form_validation->set_message("is_unique", "This {field} already exists.");

// prints "This Item Code already exists" when validation fails.
```

**Question:** How will I replace the `'%s'` into the actual `input value`? The result would be something like "*ITEM-01 already exists.*"

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can append your field value in message. Try this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message("is_unique", $this->input->post('item_name')." already exists.");
```

Comment: It prints the item_name alone sir. // ITEM-01

Comment: My bad.. I didn't recognize that period from post('item_name'). I put "," instead. Thank you sir! I never thought it was this easy!

Comment: sir, another thing.. all 'is_unique' is affected by my item_name input.. How will I separate is_unique-item_name into is_unique-item_code?

Comment: well you can use callback function for it. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like :

```
$this->form_validation->set_message("is_unique", "This {field} already exists.");
```

Try with this query, it will run definitely

Answer (score 2):

{field} is newer method.
Jors as you are using older spritf method you will have to first set human names for field in set_rules like this

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(array('field' => 'name','label' => 'Full Name','rules' => 'required'));
```

Then, format specifier %s will automatically pick that human name defined in set_rules

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('required', '%s Must be fill!');
```

Comment: thanks sir! noted. will update my code. {field} is more easier